# ajax request of form not returning expected data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that contains checkboxes, radio buttons, and text area's. Then I have three buttons, regardless of what button is clicked it should call on the same php file to handle the form data. I need to keep track of which button is pressed, because the form data is handled differently depending on the button that is pressed.

I want this to update the page without reloading or redirecting and I am having trouble with getting the ajax to work properly. The php file just contains: "`<pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>` "at the moment, I will implement a switch-case after I have the basic functionality working.

When a button is clicked, a duplicate of the form is generated on the page instead of returning the POST values.

```
<form id="form" action="calc.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="rb[]" value="one" checked> one<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb[]" value="two">two<br>
Option a<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="a">
Text a<input type="text" name="tb[]">
Option b<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="b">
Text b<input type="text" name="tb[]">  
<button id="first" class="button" name="button[]" value="first">first</button>
<button id="second" class="button" name="button[]" value="second">second</button>
<button id="third" class="button" name="button[]" value="third">third</button>
</form>


<script>
$('.button').click(function(e) {
var f = $('form').serialize();
var b = this.id;
console.log(b);
console.log(f);
$.ajax({
    data: {'button':b, 'formval': f},
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    success: function(resp){
        $('#result').html(resp);
}
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

How can I send the form values as an array along with the button that was clicked to the php file, and then have it return the result of the php file on the page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$.serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and append to the returned array in the following manner:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    var $form = $('form');
    var data = $form.serializeArray();

    data.push({ 'name': 'button', 'value': this.id }); // append button's ID

    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        success: function(resp){
            $('#result').html(resp);
        }
    });
    return false; // I don't think this is needed since your button is type="button" 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderfully and the return data from the php posted to the page in the expected format!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your context of `$(this)` inside the ajax call doesn't refer to the form, it refers to the button. so the action is null, and the ajax call returns the current page by default.

to fix, add another variable like `var form = $('form');` to reference

```html
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="form" action="calc.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="rb[]" value="one" checked> one<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb[]" value="two">two<br>
Option a<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="a">
Text a<input type="text" name="tb[]">
Option b<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="b">
Text b<input type="text" name="tb[]">  
<button id="first" class="button" name="button[]" value="first">first</button>
<button id="second" class="button" name="button[]" value="second">second</button>
<button id="third" class="button" name="button[]" value="third">third</button>
</form>

<div id='result'></div>


<script>
$('.button').click(function(e) {
// add this
var form = $('form');
var f = $('form').serialize();
var b = this.id;
console.log(b);
console.log(f);
$.ajax({
    data: {'button':b, 'formval': f},
    // change these
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    success: function(resp){
        $('#result').html(resp);
}
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: The context in the OP's code is wrong actually. `this` refer to the button, not the form. Therefore `$(this).attr('method')` would be undefined or null.

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, I don't have any clue why "loop" came out. I have edited my answer.